# Using ajax (jQuery mobile) to refresh a text file with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to put the slide value on a txt file with ajax, I found a example of how to use ajax on jQuery, but when I try to put the slider value on the function nothing happened.
Here is my HTML and PHP file:
PS: As I say before, I found a exemple on web and the example is a "calculaotor", but what I really want to do is put a slider value on a txt file.

HTML:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){

        var a = $("input[name=flip]").val();
        var b = $("input[name=num_b]").val();

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            data: { first:a, second:b },

            url: "add.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(result){
                $("#content").html('');
                $("#content").append(result);
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#loading').css({display:"block"});
            },
            complete: function(msg){
                $('#loading').css({display:"none"});
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>


                    <label for="status">Constant:</label>
                    <select name="flip" id="flip" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
                        <option value="10">O</option>
                        <option value="20">I</option>
                    </select> 


                <script>
                        $( "#flip-1").on('slidestop', function( event ) {
                           var slider_value=$("#flip-1").slider().val();
                           alert('Value: '+slider_value);
                        });
                </script>


<div id="loading" style="display: none;">Loading...</div>

<input type="text" name="num_a" />
<input type="text" name="num_b" />
<button id="btn">Add</button> 

<div id="content"></div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
    $fh = fopen("file.txt", 'w') or die("can't open file");
      fwrite($fh, $_POST["first"] + $_POST["second"]);
    fclose($fh);
    echo $_POST["first"] + $_POST["second"];
?>
```

What I'm trying to do (HTML):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){
    $( "#flip-1").on('slidestop', function( event ) {

        var a = =$("#flip-1").slider().val();
        var b = 0;

        $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        data: { first:a, second:b },

        url: "add.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(result){
            $("#content").html('');
            $("#content").append(result);
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loading').css({display:"block"});
        },
        complete: function(msg){
            $('#loading').css({display:"none"});
        }
    });
});
```

});

```
</script>


                <label for="status">Constant:</label>
                <select name="flip" id="flip" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
                    <option value="10">O</option>
                    <option value="20">I</option>
                </select> 


            <script>
                    $( "#flip-1").on('slidestop', function( event ) {
                       var slider_value=$("#flip-1").slider().val();
                       alert('Value: '+slider_value);
                        });
            </script>


<div id="loading" style="display: none;">Loading...</div>

<input type="text" name="num_a" />
<input type="text" name="num_b" />
<button id="btn">Add</button> 

<div id="content"></div>
```

I'm only want to put the slider switch value in a text file, every time that value of switch changed

Comment: firebug is your friend. You will there what is wrong with you code. Watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4jXAaEMp2M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change  `var a = $("input[name=flip]").val();`  to  `var a =
   $("#flip").val();`  because #flip is select not input
2. Debug your code on server add `print_r($_POST)` at the top of your PHP
   file, you should be getting 'first' and 'second'
3. Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to debug your AJAX request in console if you are getting
   `"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND` then your url is not pointing to
   correct address, check your code in [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f65TB/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quickly answer. I try to do this, but the code don't get the value of the slide so the return is nothing. I will  put the code of HTML to show you what I'm trying to do: